# how to pass a dynamic file path to filename field of Flexible File Writer of jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to generate the dynamic file path in the setup thread group like below.

```
def result_file = new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + File.separator + 'transactions_passed_' + new Date().format('MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss') + '.csv');
props.put("result_file",  result_file);
```

Now I want to pass that file path as a filename value of Flexible File Writer plugin of jmeter so that variables are stored inside it.

Not able to make it work. Kindly help. Thanks

I have tried below options:

```
Filename: ${__groovy(props.get("result_file").text)}
```

tried to use preprocessor and set the value:

```
vars.put("result_file",  '${__FileToString(props.get("result_file"),,)}');
```

Also tried to use below groovy script in the FileName field of Flexible File Writer, however it throws an exception of FileNotFound exception:

```
${__groovy(new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty('file.separator') + 'transactions_passed_' + new Date().format('MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss') + '.csv').text)}
```

I want to use DYNAMIC FILE PATH (which I am setting as property in setup thread group) in the FILENAME field of FLEXIBLE FILE WRITER

Answer (score 0):

The approach with [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) should work however you need to remove this `.text` bit from there

```
${__groovy(new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty('file.separator') + 'transactions_passed_' + new Date().format('MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss') + '.csv'))}
```

because `.text` returns you the file contents and as the file doesn't exist - you're getting this FileNotFound error. More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter - [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)